# Can't use jquery plugin with ng-switch

Tags: angularjs

i 'm using jquery plugin with angular , the problem is plugin works without ng-switch but doesn't work with ng-switch .
Any idea ?Thanks in advance

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/33rupjnNmMxgR4gqUURN?p=preview)

```
<ng-switch on="data">
     <div ng-switch-when="true" class="form-group">

            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInput3">تاریخ</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon" data-MdDateTimePicker="true" data-trigger="click" data-targetselector="#exampleInput3">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInput3" placeholder="تاریخ" data-MdDateTimePicker="true" data-placement="right" />
            </div>
        </div>
       <div class="leftWrapper" ng-switch-default>
          say Hi

        </div>
      </ng-switch>
```

Comment: When are you initializing the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work is Jquery plugin *has no idea* to where to send click event (in your case) when `ng-if` recreates DOM. And for sure it doesn't trigger digest cycle.

To make it work you can do it by two ways:

- or create [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for jQuery plugin *(for me more appropriate)*
- or change to `ng-show/hide` see <kbd>[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/RqwmniWl7GNTOZXu4NkF?p=preview)</kbd>. `ngShow` directive shows or hides the given HTML element on CSS level

---

For DOCS see [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

Comment: many thanks Maxim , you helped me a lot , one more question : is it a good idea to convert that to a directive ?(because it's kind of large plugin)
if it's good , can i use ng-switch with this directive ?

Comment: @sani sure, this is a goal of directive to work with 3d party plugins